# Is there a simple way to specify a global dependency exclude in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, slf4j, finagle, twitter-finagle

How would you exclude a transitive dependency globally? My project depends on a lot of the Twitter libraries or on libraries that depend on the Twitter libraries. I don't want `slf4j-jdk14` in my classpath, no matter what (I use logback as slf4j binding).

Currently I do this:

```
"com.twitter" %% "finagle-thriftmux" % "6.16.0" exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-jdk14")
```

but every time someone adds another dependency that uses `slf4j-jdk14` I might get it back into the classpath.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Since sbt 0.13.8**

In sbt 0.13.8 there is [possibility](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html#Project-level+dependency+exclusions) to exclude dependencies globally. Here is a compact example:

```
excludeDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-jdk14"
```

However, at the moment of writing this feature was marked as experimental so it's wise to be aware of older solution.

**Before sbt 0.13.8**

For a group of dependencies you can do it as follows:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-thriftmux" % "6.16.0",
  "com.twitter" % "lib" % "2.0",
  "com.domain" % "some-other-lib" % "1.0"
).map(_.exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-jdk14"))
```

Answer (score 50):

`excludeDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-jdk14"`

Comment: This solution seems more elegant to me than the accepted one

Comment: The accepted answer was written when this solution wasn't available in sbt.

Answer (score 6):

```
libraryDependencies := libraryDependencies.value.map(_.exclude("groupid", "artifactname"))
```