# What is the difference between jetty:start and jetty:quickstart in xsbt-web-plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, jetty, xsbt-web-plugin

I am running a scala 2.11.12 app on lift 3.3.0 built with sbt 1.3.8. I have tried 4.0.3 and 4.2.0 of xsbt-web-plugin. My app launches fine when I use jetty:start but when I use jetty:quickstart  it fails to launch - I get a 500 error in the browser and when I check the application log in the console I see java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()' which causes the jetty instance to give back a 500.

** edit ive gone back further in my logile

What is the difference between how quickstart runs and how start runs? I cant figure out the problem.

Below is my build.sbt in case it helps. Below that Ive include the console logs for the request in jetty:quickstart showing the error Im getting. I dont get this error for jetty:start.

** edit 2
Ive jun jetty:start then show update, and jetty:quickstart then show update.
They both have javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5:default as a dependency. But jetty:start works fine and starts the container, while jetty:quickstart fails to initialize the container. I'm at a loss to understand why one works and one fails - it seems to me both should fail.

** edit 3 I figured out why servlet-api 2.5 was coming in, and have updated the paypal dependencies to fix that. I'd still love to know why jetty:start worked but jetty:quickstart didnt - they both seemingly should've failed.

build.sbt

```
name := "knot-core"

organization := "com.postrope"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

excludeFilter := HiddenFileFilter -- ".ebextensions"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype scala-tools releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Sonatype scala-tools snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "3.3.0"
  Seq(
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",
    "junit" % "junit" % "4.7" % "test",
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.0.0",
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.0",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.19",
    "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup" % "tagsoup" % "1.2",
    "net.liftmodules" %% "paypal_3.0" % "1.3.0",
    "com.paypal.sdk" % "adaptivepaymentssdk" % "2.6.110",
    "com.paypal.sdk" % "adaptiveaccountssdk" % "2.4.106",
    "org.apache.solr" % "solr-solrj" % "4.4.0",
    "org.imgscalr" % "imgscalr-lib" % "4.2",
    "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.7.3",
    "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.7.3",
    "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "3.9.1",
    "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-chrome-driver" % "3.9.1",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1" % "test",
    "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2",
    "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.8.10",
    "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.10",
    "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-oauth" % "0.8.10",
    "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http-json" % "0.8.10"
  )
}

enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
javaOptions in Jetty ++= Seq(
  "-Xdebug",
  "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"
)

//jRebel class reload support

Seq(JRebelPlugin.jrebelSettings: _*)

jrebelWebLinks += (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "webapp"

jrebelEnabled := true

javaOptions in Jetty ++= Seq(
  "-agentpath:C:\\Users\\drewb\\tools\\jrebel-2020.2.0\\lib\\jrebel64.dll",
)
```

Error in jetty:quickstart

```
02:03:55.221 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - REQUEST for //localhost:8080/ on HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=1}
GET //localhost:8080/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.498072716.1587178043; _gid=GA1.1.223715266.1587738288; JSESSIONID=node01b1y37p1yogb5tgcxs7c0pofr0.node0; _gat=1


02:03:55.221 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=2} onContentComplete
02:03:55.222 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=3} onRequestComplete
02:03:55.222 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput - HttpInputOverHTTP@243824e[c=0,q=0,[0]=null,s=STREAM] addContent EOF
02:03:55.222 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.HttpConnection - HttpConnection@70d9094a::SocketChannelEndPoint@7785c24d{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55305<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=19/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70d9094a[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@43f6ae01{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=3} parsed true HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1}
02:03:55.223 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.HttpConnection - releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@70d9094a::SocketChannelEndPoint@7785c24d{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55305<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=19/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70d9094a[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@43f6ae01{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=4}
02:03:55.224 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=5} handle //localhost:8080/
02:03:55.224 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - handling HttpChannelState@69b6a9e2{s=IDLE a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false}
02:03:55.227 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=8} action DISPATCH
02:03:55.229 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST GET / on HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=10}
02:03:55.229 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/ @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a45193b{/,file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/}
02:03:55.232 [qtp101874302-67] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()'
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.doError(ErrorHandler.java:138) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:74) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:454) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:391) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.checkContext(ContextHandler.java:1108) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1149) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:494) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:374) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:268) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:918) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
02:03:55.232 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - onError HttpChannelState@69b6a9e2{s=DISPATCHED a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false} {}
02:03:55.232 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - unhandle HttpChannelState@69b6a9e2{s=THROWN a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false}
02:03:55.232 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=13} action ERROR_DISPATCH
02:03:55.234 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - ERROR GET / on HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=false,c=false/false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=15}
02:03:55.234 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/ @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a45193b{/,file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/}
02:03:55.234 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/ @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a45193b{/,file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/}
02:03:55.236 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.j.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler - getErrorPage(GET /) => error_page=null (from global default)
02:03:55.236 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ErrorHandler - No Error Page mapping for request(GET /) (using default)
02:03:55.237 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - Could not perform ERROR dispatch, aborting
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()'
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.doError(ErrorHandler.java:138) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:74) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:454) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doError(AbstractHandler.java:93) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1301) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:42003) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:190) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1204) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:494) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:429) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:268) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:918) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
02:03:55.238 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - sendResponse info=null content=HeapByteBuffer@47b52cca[p=0,l=0,c=0,r=0]={<<<>>>} complete=false committing=true callback=Blocker@4483efeb{null}
02:03:55.238 [qtp101874302-67] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - COMMIT for / on HttpChannelOverHttp@c1f8711{r=1,c=true,c=false/false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/,age=19}
500 null HTTP/1.1
```

Container initialisation error

```
11:21:49.793 [main] DEBUG o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - isServerClass==true class org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter
11:21:49.793 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED ServletContainerInitializersStarter@285f09de{FAILED}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.descriptor.JspConfigDescriptor javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.descriptor.JspConfigDescriptor javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()'
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJspConfig(TldScanner.java:158) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:102) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:141) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1443) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1407) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:821) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:276) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:106) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:520) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:565) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:9.4.20.v20190813]
11:21:49.794 [main] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4bd1f8dd{/,file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/drewb/IdeaProjects/knot-alpha/src/main/webapp/
```

Comment: The main difference between `start` and `quickstart` is that the latter skips packaging your project, and runs Jetty with your project's classpath from sbt.  This error looks like that classpath has a runtime dependency on an old version of servlet-api.  Can you inspect your dependency tree?  You might also try adding an explicit servlet-api dependency: `libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"`

Comment: Thanks James. I''ve found file:/C:/Users/drewb/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar on my classpath for jetty:quickstart and I guess this is causing the error. I am trying to figure out how I can identify who is bringing in this dependency so I can get rid of it.

Comment: This will help you track down which dependency depends on servlet-api-2.5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519926/how-to-see-dependency-tree-in-sbt

Comment: This will help you block servlet-api-2.5, either as a transitive dependency via `exclude`, or just globally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747900/is-there-a-simple-way-to-specify-a-global-dependency-exclude-in-sbt

Comment: Re: edit2 and edit3, I modified the answer below to explain why you see a difference between `start` and `quickstart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jetty:start` and `jetty:quickstart` commands both come from [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin).  Note that `jetty:quickstart` is unrelated to the [Quickstart Webapps](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html) feature of Jetty.

The main difference between the two is that `start` builds a complete package of your project and `quickstart` does not.  With `quickstart`, no *.war* file is created, your classes are not packaged up in a *.jar* file, etc.

With `quickstart`, Jetty is run using your project's runtime classpath as managed by sbt.  With `start`, Jetty is run with only your project's package, and the dependencies it contains as *.jar* files.  These can differ, as sbt's runtime classpath will include dependencies in the `provided` scope, while your package will not.  This is why one is working for you, and the other is not.

Your error:

> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()'
> ```

Indicates that you have a [version conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730096/javax-servlet-http-httpservletresponse-getstatus-not-found) between the `servlet-api` *.jar* on your classpath, and the one that Jetty expects.  One or more of your project's dependencies must have a transitive dependency on an old version of `servlet-api`.

There are multiple ways to [inspect the dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519926/how-to-see-dependency-tree-in-sbt).  Using Coursier, I see that your two Paypal libraries both depend on `servlet-api` 2.5:

```
├─ com.paypal.sdk:adaptiveaccountssdk:2.4.106
│  └─ com.paypal.sdk:paypal-core:1.4.4
│     ├─ com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2 -> 2.8.2 (possible incompatibility)
│     ├─ commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6 -> 1.11 (possible incompatibility)
│     └─ javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
├─ com.paypal.sdk:adaptivepaymentssdk:2.6.110
│  └─ com.paypal.sdk:paypal-core:1.4.4
│     ├─ com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2 -> 2.8.2 (possible incompatibility)
│     ├─ commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6 -> 1.11 (possible incompatibility)
│     └─ javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
```

This needs to be excluded, as it is too old for the version of Jetty you're using.

There are multiple ways to [exclude transitive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747900/is-there-a-simple-way-to-specify-a-global-dependency-exclude-in-sbt) in sbt.  By adding `exclude("javax.servlet", "servlet-api")` to both of your Paypal dependencies, we can block the conflicting version of `servlet-api`:

```
"com.paypal.sdk" % "adaptivepaymentssdk" % "2.6.110" exclude("javax.servlet", "servlet-api"),
"com.paypal.sdk" % "adaptiveaccountssdk" % "2.4.106" exclude("javax.servlet", "servlet-api"),
```

You'll also want to add a recent one to `provided` scope so your code can compile:

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What still confuses me is why jetty:start works and jetty:quickstart doesnt - the app has the same dependencies in both cases doesn it?

Comment: jetty:quickstart needs the quickstart metadata (the `WEB-INF/quickstart-web.xml`) to work, which is a different build time step.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It sounds like it describes Quickstart Webapps[1], but xsbt-web-plugin's `quickstart`[2] is unrelated to that.  In hindsight, it should have been named differently to avoid confusion.

[1]: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html
[2]: https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/4.1.x.md#quickstart-mode

Comment: Thanks James. Given theyre running the same compiled classes any thoughts on why the app runs fine under jetty:start but throws a server error for jetty:quickstart?

Comment: @earldouglas feel free to update/modify my answer (or write your own) :-)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks; I made some modifications to your answer.