# How to exclude log4j vulnerable transitive dependencies in SBT?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, log4j

How to exclude log4j 1.2.17 vulnerable from all dependencies in build.sbt

We are using Sbt (0.13.11) based Play framework application as mentioned configuration in the attachment, we want to exclude dependencies related to vulnerable log4j 1.2.17.

```
name := """xxxx"""

version := "1.0"

lazy val playCommonDI = (project in file("./modules/play-common-di")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
lazy val libsf = (project in file("libsf"))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, SbtWeb)
  .aggregate(playCommonDI, libsf)
  .dependsOn(playCommonDI, libsf)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions := Seq("-feature", "-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://deadbolt.ws/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += "(Plugins) Project Maven Repo" at "file://" + file(".").getCanonicalPath + "/local-repo/maven/"


val junitVersion = "5.4.0"

val apachePOIVersion = "4.1.2"
val apachePOIDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % apachePOIVersion,
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % apachePOIVersion,
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml-schemas" % apachePOIVersion
)
libraryDependencies ++= apachePOIDependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  filters,

  // Tests
  "org.junit.platform" % "junit-platform-launcher" % "1.4.0" % Test,
  "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-engine" % junitVersion % Test,
  "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-params" % junitVersion % Test,
  "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-api" % junitVersion % Test,

  "org.dhatim" % "fastexcel" % "0.12.15",

  "com.akamai" % "edgeauth" % "0.2.0",

  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.23.4" % Test,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-junit-jupiter" % "2.23.4" % Test,

  "net.aichler" % "jupiter-interface" % JupiterKeys.jupiterVersion.value % Test,
  "org.jacoco" % "org.jacoco.core" % "0.8.3",

  "org.testcontainers" % "testcontainers" % "1.9.1" % Test,
  "org.testcontainers" % "jdbc" % "1.9.1" % Test,
  "org.testcontainers" % "mysql" % "1.9.1" % Test,

  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.31",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.3.2",
  "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.4.0",
  "com.thoughtworks.xstream" % "xstream" % "1.4.4",
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.5.6",
  "org.ocpsoft.prettytime"%"prettytime"%"3.2.5.Final",

  "dom4j" % "dom4j" % "1.6.1",
  "net.logstash.logback" % "logstash-logback-encoder" % "4.11",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.5",
  "org.redisson" % "redisson" % "2.6.0",
  "org.atmosphere" % "atmosphere-play" % "2.3.0",
  "org.atmosphere" % "wasync" % "2.1.4",
  "com.hazelcast" % "hazelcast" % "3.4.2",
  "com.hazelcast" % "hazelcast-cloud" % "3.4.2",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.5.0",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-exec" % "1.3",
  "net.htmlparser.jericho" % "jericho-html" % "3.4",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-csv" % "1.2",
  "com.itextpdf" % "itextpdf" % "5.5.11",
  "com.itextpdf.tool" % "xmlworker" % "5.5.11",
  "com.hierynomus" % "sshj" % "0.21.1",
  "com.onelogin" % "java-saml" % "2.0.1",
  "com.rusticisoftware" % "tincan" % "1.1.0",
  
  "com.tokbox" % "opentok-server-sdk" % "4.3.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.asynchttpclient")
  ),
  "org.bitbucket.b_c" % "jose4j" % "0.6.4",
  
  "com.pusher" % "pusher-http-java" % "1.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote_2.11" % "2.4.17",
  "org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.56",

  "org.flywaydb" %% "flyway-play" % "3.2.0",

  "org.togglz" % "togglz-core" % "2.6.1.Final",
  "org.togglz" % "togglz-console" % "2.6.1.Final",
  "org.togglz" % "togglz-testing" % "2.6.1.Final" % Test,
  "org.togglz" % "togglz-junit" % "2.6.1.Final" % Test,

  "com.twilio.sdk" % "twilio" % "7.32.0",

  "com.google.inject.extensions" % "guice-multibindings" % "4.0"
)

dependencyOverrides += "net.bytebuddy" % "byte-buddy" % "1.9.3"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.9"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.9.1"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.9.9"

parallelExecution in Global := false

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

//API Documentation
sources in (Compile, doc) := Seq.empty

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false

//CSS assets
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"

excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"

LessKeys.compress in Assets := true

//JSHint
JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node

//Digest
pipelineStages := Seq(uglify, digest, gzip)

//Exclude documentation in dist
doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none")

//SBT + Scala + idea support required (2.12?): Keys.javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint:unchecked")
Keys.javacOptions += "-Xlint:deprecation"

Keys.javacOptions += "-Xlint:unchecked"

// Enable testes to run in it's own VM
Keys.fork in Test := true

ivyConfiguration ~= { originalIvyConfiguration =>
  val config = originalIvyConfiguration.asInstanceOf[InlineIvyConfiguration]
  val ivyHome = file(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/ivy2_sbt-plugin-2.5.14")
  val ivyPaths = new IvyPaths(config.paths.baseDirectory, Some(ivyHome))
  new InlineIvyConfiguration(ivyPaths, config.resolvers, config.otherResolvers,
    config.moduleConfigurations, config.localOnly, config.lock,
    config.checksums, config.resolutionCacheDir, config.log)
}

jacocoReportSettings in Test := JacocoReportSettings().withTitle("xxxx Report")
```

As mentioned in the build file, we tried to mention the proper log4j 2.17, seems default one log4j 1.2.17 is not getting replaced with new version of log4j.

Can you please help us on this ?

Comment: There's nothing in your build.sbt that relates to log4j.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to specify a global dependency exclude in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747900/is-there-a-simple-way-to-specify-a-global-dependency-exclude-in-sbt)

Comment: You'll have to explicitly add the replacement version from reload4j in your build.sbt if your code relies on log4j 1.x.

Comment: Last thing: you're using very very old versions of almost everything! SBT, Scala, Play, Jackson.. Your project already has many vulnerabilities because of this. I would strongly recommend to spend some time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with excluding log4j 1.2, is that log4j2 doesn't replace it. That's why adding a dependency on log4j2 doesn't work. They are completely different libraries. They have different artifact IDs (log4j 1.2 can be found at `log4j:log4j`, while log4j2 uses `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api`), they use different Java package names (log4j 1.2 uses `org.apache.log4j`, while log4j2 uses `org.apache.logging.log4j`). They just happen to both have the word `log4j` in their name, but from a build tool/dependency managers perspective, they share nothing in common, so when you tell your build to use log4j2, the build tool has no idea that that package has any relation to log4j 1, and keeps both in your dependencies.

It's obviously being brought in by one of your dependencies. If you exclude it, most likely, the dependency that brings it in will stop working, because when it loads, it will try to load the log4j 1.2 API, which won't be on the classpath, and so it'll fail with class not found errors.

The work around is to use [reload4j](https://reload4j.qos.ch/). This provides a binary compatible implementation of the log4j 1.2 APIs, but with major security vulnerabilities fixed.

To do this, you need to identify which of your dependencies depends on log4j 1.2. You can do this using the sbt dependency tree plugin, a tutorial on how to use this can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-dependency-tree).

Then, exclude log4j from those dependencies transitive dependencies, as [documented here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies).

Finally, you can add reload4j as a dependency to your project.

Better than all this would be to update your project to stop using very old versions of libraries at all. The last version of Play to support sbt 0.13.11 was Play 2.5, released in 2016. Play 2.6 replaced it in 2017. Play 2.5 support finished in 2018. You're using a version of Play that's been unsupported for over 5 years. Look at all these security vulnerabilities that have been fixed in Play since then that you're probably vulnerable to, many of the vulnerabilities reported since 2018 Play 2.5.x would be vulnerable to, it's just that because Play 2.5 is out of support, we don't list those vulnerabilities against it:

https://www.playframework.com/security/vulnerability

Not to mention all the vulnerabilities in the dependencies you're using.